# How do you handle a PATCH request from HTMX in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, htmx

I would like to send a PATCH request to my app but I'm not sure how to consume the request in Django. I am currently getting the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'PATCH'
```

The input field in the HTMX file looks like this (I also made sure to send the CSRF token):

```
<input 
        name="myfield"
        hx-patch="{% url 'my_update' myobj.id %}"
        hx-swap="none" />
```

This is the Django View

```
class MyHtmxView(View):

def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = MyForm(request.PATCH)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # return an okay status? 200?
    else:
        return HttpResponse(self.form_invalid(form))
```

Django is receiving the request, but isn't sure what to do with request.PATCH. I can see in the Django docs that there is a HttpRequest.GET and HttpRequest.POST but no HttpRequest.PATCH https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects. What's the best way to handle the PATCH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to parse the request body manually which can be accessed via `request.body` and parse using `QueryDict(request.body)`

```py
from django.http.request import QueryDict
 
class MyHtmxView(View):

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        # parse request body mannualy
        data = QueryDict(request.body)

        form = MyForm(data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # return an okay status? 200?
        else:
            return HttpResponse(self.form_invalid(form))
```

Comment: When using this, I don't get anything passed to the `patch` method.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects), your form info will be in the `request.POST` attribute. You can check for `PATCH`s with `if request.method == "PATCH"`.

Comment: Thanks. Have you had this work before? In my code, if I send a post request `hx-post` I can see the data inside request.POST, but when using `hx-patch` the request.POST is empty.